# CSS module not changing DOM/markup classnames - parcel bundler

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, parcel

I am trying to add autoprefixer using CSS modules. Parcel is the bundler I am using for my React app.

On build, the CSS names change, but the DOM tree that is constructed has class names I wrote previously , not the modified class names with prefixes.

My package.json file looks like -

```
  "postcss": {
    "modules": true,
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": true
    }
  }
```